# Linux screenlets : can I remove the options from the menu?

Tags: linux

I use "Screenlets" on my Ubuntu PC, primarily so that I can have a bigger trashcan?

[image]

Can I remove all those options? I only want "open" and "empty". I can still find the other options in the screenlet manager app.

Comment: Bigger trashcan? Is there a size limit to the trash can on Ubuntu? Or are you talking about the icon? Currently, the best advice seems to be to stop using that Screenlet thingy.

Comment: I also use them for other things. I'd like to hide the options, once they are set up.

Comment: I also liked the trashcan screenlet, i found it "prettier", and it can show the number of items in it. But those are small improvements, I guess I'll just use the regular trashcan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of open source is that with enough effort anything is possible. In your case you're lucky that it's pretty easy.

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/screenlets/Trash/TrashScreenlet.py
```

then add a `#` character to the beginning of line 138 so that it reads:

```
# self.add_default_menuitems()
```

Save the document and restart your screenlets and only Empty Trash and Open Trash should be left in the context menu for your trash screenlet. Remove the `#` to restore the default functionality.

**However**, I'm skeptical that you should want to do this; it hides some important functionality that I'm not sure is duplicated elsewhere. Tread lightly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I'll ask the Screenlet people about this. I don't need to change the options of the screenlets every minutes, so it complicates my desktop.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, however you can increase the size of icons on your desktop, such as the recycle bin.

*`Right-click` => `Stretch Icon`*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. But I use screenlets for other things.